# ASP.NET MVC 5 and WCF async troubles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, async-await

Our application uses WCF as data provider and on some pages we have a multiple calls to different services. Good piece to optimize I thought, and started to rewrite it to the `async`. So before the rewrite it looks like

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int id)
{
var r1 = AService.Call1();
var r2 = BService.Call2();
var r3 = CService.Call3();
//another logic
}
```

and now it turned to

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SomeAction(int id)
{
var r1 = await AService.Call1Async();
var r2 = await BService.Call2Async();
var r3 = await CService.Call3Async();
//another logic
}
```

With this approach I faced two problems:

1. After first service call application falls into unending loading and
   no other actions performed. Debugging show the same — first call and
   nothing after that.
2. Some of our classes won't work with async methods, a.e. our static AuthorizationProvider.

**Update:** @zuckerberg answer helps with optimization (I'm creating tasks and putting them in awaitable `Task.WhenAll()`), but I'm still getting hangs on WCF services — while synchronous calls going correctly, asynchronous calls turning calling logic to sleep and never awakes it back.

Comment: Are you blocking on any of those `CallAsync`.

Comment: Your adaptation to async/await looks OK. So there must be something else at play but nobody here can look in your PC. So start setting up that [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

with async/await they run asynchronously. Which means they don't wait for each other or the main thread. If there are dependancies or you need to wait for all 3 to finish first before returning a result, then I suggest using something like:

```
var r1 = await AService.Call1Async();
var r2 = await BService.Call2Async();
var r3 = await CService.Call3Async();

await Task.WhenAll(r1, r2, r3);
//more logic
```

Hope this helps nudge you in the right direction. However, without seeing more code, I can't tell if by just async/await'ing your calls will actually improve performance or not (it's not always a performance booster) and your time/effort might be better spent elsewhere.

Good luck!

Comment: Kinda helps, so thank thou. Needs more research, especially about hanging and usage inside our AuthorizationProvider.

Comment: Your answer is wrong and that code would never compile, unless `CallAsync` returns `Tasl<Task>`.

Comment: You can't await twice. But moreover, the async calls in the question _are executed sequentially_.  Your assumption is wrong.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I actually copied and modified an example off of an accepted answer on SO and adjusted it to the OP's example. I didn't write code that can compile. It was to explain. I also mentioned that without more code I can't say for sure. I'm trying to give them the right idea, not code. Always easier to comment and tear down others' attempts, how about posting your own answer.

Comment: @bommelding Like I said, it all depends on what the OP is doing and the code given isn't all that much helpful with "more logic" as a comment. I had to assume the await they're doing isn't part of the method's async, meaning the part with "more logic" could be the return await *thing* of the main thread. You can indeed await as many times as you'd like within a method. But if you know the answer, I would love you post one so we can see?

Comment: Yes, you can await r1 and r2 etc. But you can't await r1 twice. I won't have an answer as long as there is no question.

Comment: @bommelding not sure why you're a part of this then if you felt you'd rather not contribute but criticize. I don't see where r1 is being await'ed twice, but like I said, I just used it as an example to hopefully push OP to the correct answer as the code he shared lacks a bit of context in the overall picture

Comment: We all take part in improving and criticizing. Your opening statement "Which means they don't wait for each other" is very false. An ongoing misconception about async/await that must be suppressed.

Comment: I apologize. I was explaining it in a very simplistic and wrong way.

Comment: You can still _delete_ this answer.

Comment: @bommelding, you can await any task as many times as you want.

Comment: Yes, but putting a bunch of completed Tasks into WhenAll() is not making much sense.

Answer (score 0):

1.Starting functions with inner async calls from constructor of static class is a bad idea, but `SomeMethodAsync().Result` helps — of course there's no benefit for controller, but in that little case it acceptable.

2.Yes, I misunderstood `async/await`, so I rewrite code to something like this:

```
var get1Task = AService.Call1Async();
var get2Task = BService.Call2Async();
var get3Task = CService.Call3Async();

await Task.WhenAll(get1Task, get2Task, get3Task);
var r1 = get1Task.Result;
var r2 = get2Task.Result;
var r3 = get3Task.Result;
//more logic
```

It gave me a good speedup on pages with lot of WCF calls and I'm kinda happy.

My thanks going to @zuckerberg for pointing to the right direction.